# unexpected behavior when using calendar type in java

Tags: java, calendar

When I'm debugging through each step to initialize the calendar the date is correctly set to 31.07.2016. But when I step over the calendar method the date is wrongly set to 02.08.2016. Can anybody explain this unexpected behavior?

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calendar startCalendar = initializeCalendar("31.07.2016");
    }

    private static Calendar initializeCalendar(String date)
    {
        int[] dateValues = extractDate(date);

        Calendar calendar = createCalendar();

        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateValues[0]);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, dateValues[1]-1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, dateValues[2]);

        return calendar;
    }

    private static Calendar createCalendar()
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.clear();

        return calendar;
    }

    private static int[] extractDate(String date)
    {
        String[] ddmmyyy = date.split("\\.");

        return new int[]{Integer.parseInt(ddmmyyy[0]), Integer.parseInt(ddmmyyy[1]), Integer.parseInt(ddmmyyy[2])};
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your posted code with comments on lines where the date is correct and incorrect?

Comment: This works correctly. And why not use a `SimpleDateFormat`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel use `SimpleDateFormat` instead as next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    // Define the corresponding format
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Parse "31.07.2016" and set the resulting date to the calendar instance
    startCalendar.setTime(format.parse("31.07.2016"));
    // Print the formatted date
    System.out.println(format.format(startCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

**Output:**

```
31.07.2016
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know the type SimpleDateFormat.